# Pivot Table with 3 Columns to get the value in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I am a new in Laravel and I am trying to get the value from third column id in pivot table

I have 3 tables and 4th table is pivot table, so my table structure is as follow

1. TABLE Product Structure

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
   });
```

2. Table Attributes Structure

```
   Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

3. Table Attribute Value Structure

```
 Schema::create('attribute_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('value');
            $table->foreignId('attribute_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

4. and I also make pivot table attribute_product

```
 Schema::create('attribute_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('attribute_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('attribute_value_id')->constrained();
        });
```

<<<<<<<<<<<  MODELS OF TABLE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
1.Table Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class)->using(AttributeProduct::class)->withPivot('attribute_value_id');
    }
    
 }
```

2.Table Attribute

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->using(AttributeProduct::class)->withPivot('attribute_value_id');
    }

}
```

3. Table Attribute Value

```
class AttributeValue extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function attribute_product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeProduct::class, 'attribute_value_id');
    }


 }
```

AND also I make a model of pivot table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class AttributeProduct extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function value()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AttributeValue::class,'attribute_value_id');
    }
}
```

<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DATA IN TABLES >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

1. TABLE PRODUCT

```
ID   TITLE           category_id
6    Samsung S22        2
```

2. TABLE ATTRIBUTE

```
ID    NAME
1     SIZE
2     COLOR
```

3. TABLE ATTRIBUTE VALUES

```
ID   VALUE     attribute_id
1     SM           1
2      M           1
3     RED          2
4     BLUE         2
```

4. Pivot Table values attribute_product

```
product_id   attribute_id   attribute_value_id 
  6              1                 1
  6              2                 4
```

Now I am using these commands in controller to find the value

```
$p = Product::find(6);

foreach($p->attributes as $value){
   echo $value->name." = ". $value->pivot->attribute_value_id->value."<br>";
}
```

when I try to get the value on base of attribute_value_id from pivot table its give me this error

```
ErrorException

Attempt to read property "value" on int
```

So how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pivot relation `value` should be a `hasOne`, not a `belongsTo`.

```
class AttributeProduct extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function value()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AttributeValue::class, 'id', 'attribute_value_id');
    }
}
```

So in your `foreach`, you can now do:

```
foreach($p->attributes as $attribute){
   echo $attribute->name." = ". $attribute->pivot->value->value."<br>";
}
```

Also try to keep your variable names straight. Don't write `$p->attributes as $value` if `$value` is clearly an `$attribute`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I also try your solution and its work and learn a lot of things. Thanks once again

Comment: This is definitly a better way than I suggested, thanks for the info!